# read Json into Scalaz Tree

Tags: scala, playframework, tree, playframework-2.0, scalaz

Scala newbie here.

I use Play to provide a json API for reading and writing a directory like structure. Therefore I use Scalaz.Tree, which provides ways of traversing, updating and rebuilding the Tree.

Formatting the Tree into json works well:

```
case class File(id: String = BSONObjectID.generate.toString(), name: String, noteBookId: String = null)
implicit val fileFormat: Format[File] = Json.format[File]

implicit def treeWrites: Writes[Tree[File]] =
new Writes[Tree[File]] {
  def writes(o: Tree[File]) = o match {
    case Node(file, children) => Json.obj(
      "name" -> file.name,
      "id" -> file.id,
      "children" -> JsArray(children.map(Json.toJson(_))),
      "notebookId" -> file.noteBookId
    )
  }
}
```

Reading json into a Tree however, fails

```
implicit def treeReads: Reads[Tree[File]] = (
  //(__ \ "children").lazyRead(Reads.seq[File](treeReads)) and
  (__ \ "children").read[Tree[File]] and
  (__ \ "name").read[String] and 
  (__ \ "notebookid").read[String] and // <-- this is line 41, where the error message points at!!
  (__ \ "id").read[String]
)(apply _)

implicit val treeFormat: Format[Tree[File]] = Format(treeReads, treeWrites)
```

The error I am getting:

```
[error] /home/dikken/Development/core-service-spaas/app/models/dirTree.scala:41: overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
[error]   [B](f: B => (scalaz.Tree[model.treedir.File], String, String, String))(implicit fu: play.api.libs.functional.ContravariantFunctor[play.api.libs.json.Reads])play.api.libs.json.Reads[B] <and>
[error]   [B](f: (scalaz.Tree[model.treedir.File], String, String, String) => B)(implicit fu: play.api.libs.functional.Functor[play.api.libs.json.Reads])play.api.libs.json.Reads[B]
[error]  cannot be applied to ((=> Nothing) => scalaz.Tree[Nothing])
[error]     (__ \ "id").read[String] and
[error]                              ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

Does this mean I have to pattern match on a case where I have a Tree of Nothing? And how excatly should I do that?

Any help appreciated! Tx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume that `apply _` is actually `File.apply _`, which cannot work here. `File.apply` accepts the parameters of the case class `File` (of which there are three). With JSON combinators, it is trying to pass the four parameters above to `File.apply`, which does not mix. It *also* does not produce a `Tree[File]`. What you need to do is replace `File.apply` with a method that accepts (children, notebookid, name, id) as parameters, and produces a `Tree[File]`.

Here's a somewhat crude one that will work:

```
def jsonToTree(children: Seq[Tree[File]], name: String, notebookid: String, id: String): Tree[File] =
    Tree.node(File(id, name, notebookid), children.toStream)
```

The `Reads` will now look more like this:

```
implicit def treeReads: Reads[Tree[File]] = (
  (__ \ "children").lazyRead[Seq[Tree[File]]](Reads.seq(treeReads)).orElse(Reads.pure(Nil)) and
  (__ \ "name").read[String] and 
  (__ \ "notebookid").read[String] and
  (__ \ "id").read[String]
)(jsonToTree _)
```

You were closer with the commented out line as well. Because this is a recursive structure, we need to use `lazyRead`.

Testing:

```
val js = Json.parse("""{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "test",
    "notebookid": "abc",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "test222",
            "notebookid": "ijk"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "test333",
            "notebookid": "xyz"
        }
    ]
}""")

scala> val tree = js.as[Tree[File]]
tree: scalaz.Tree[File] = <tree>

scala> tree.rootLabel
res8: File = File(1,test,abc)

scala> tree.subForest
res9: Stream[scalaz.Tree[File]] = Stream(<tree>, ?)
```

This can also be done (certainly in different ways) without combinators, as well (provided there is an implicit `Reads[File]` available):

```
implicit def treeReads: Reads[Tree[File]] = new Reads[Tree[File]] {
    def reads(js: JsValue): JsResult[Tree[File]] = {
        js.validate[File] map { case file =>
            (js \ "children").validate[Stream[Tree[File]]].fold(
                _        => Tree.leaf(file),
                children => Tree.node(file, children)
            )
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: tx! that would have taken a looong time to figure out myself